# How can there be an eleventh dimension if the tenth is the last?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory, spacetime-dimensions

So in string theory (or to be precise, F theory) we have an eleven dimensional torus over the ten space dimensions and this torus vibrations give us the supergravity theory. But my question is, when I follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ca4miMMaCE), it seems as if the tenth dimension is the final dimension and there can't be any dimension over this so how does a 11 dimensional torus look like ?

Please do not put my question on hold, this is relevant physics.

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia: [10D string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory); [11D M-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory); [12D F-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-theory).

Comment: but in M theory the 11th dimension is not a real dimension as it just is added by mathematicans (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Witten). It is not "real" in the sense that we could expect to get a grasp on it unlike the physical eleven dimensional torus.

Comment: **how does a 11 dimensional torus look like ?**  As we  can't even imagine a 4 D world without using projections, shadows, 3D analogies  etc, I honestly don't think it's worth your time even trying.  Personally, I can't  look at a CY shape without needing headache tablets.

Comment: But if you look at the video you can just think of the 4th dimension as time and it is easy to look at time as the clock always tells us times. Just as looking at your measurng tape gives you a look at the length dimension.
by the way,@TáMéCeart what is a CY shape ?

Comment: @StringTheoretican   I am currently reading "The Shape of Inner Space" by Yau,  and intended to  mean a Calabi-Yau manifold.   I just got going on the foothills of String Theory, so if this is terrible wording (or understanding) on my part, I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video that you are watching is known to be an exceptionally bad way to learn about higher-dimensional spaces. The use of time to visualize a fourth dimension is OK, but by the time it gets to the 5th dimension the video takes a detour into relatively crazy land. Certainly you should not take it as a well-known physical reality of "these are the 10 dimensions of space."

In particular, it's worth trying to think about taking a Möbius strip, as seen in the video: its boundary is some simple curve that closes in on itself, so it is topologically equivalent to a circle, and in 4D space you can probably deform it so that the Möbius strip is some complicated 2D surface bounded by a circle. You can then cut a little hole in a sphere and "glue" the Möbius strip to the sphere, to get a 2D surface without a boundary. Now suppose I ask you, "OK so the Möbius strip was non-orientable, and we know the Klein bottle is a 2D non-orientable surface without a boundary: is the surface that we just constructed a Klein bottle, or not?" -- I think you do not get enough of a sense of the 4th dimension to even begin to visualize this question, much less analyze it.

Similarly you might ask whether your ability to visualize these different dimensions has answered the following question: imagine we tile a 3D cubic lattice with balls, so there is a ball at $(i,j,k)$ for all integer $i,j,k$, and we'll give those radius $1/2$ so that they are all touching. Now this lattice nevertheless has a little gap, say at $(1/2, 1/2, 1/2),$ in the middle of these balls into which we could insert another ball. First off: what is the volume of the largest ball that could go in there, in 3D? Secondly: as we go to higher and higher dimensional space, does the ball shrink relative to the other balls in the lattice, or does it get larger, or what? If it shrinks, is there a limit to how it shrinks or does it shrink to 0? Or if it grows, what dimension is it where if I put a ball in at $(1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, \dots)$ then I better not put a ball at $(-1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2, \dots)$ because they actually are so large that they bulge out of the unit hypercube, intersecting in a neighborhood around, at the very least, $(0, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2).$ If you do not have a grasp of these things then I think you are just eating a topological "candy bar" and getting an unhealthy quick-fix, not sitting down for a proper topological "dinner" that will nourish your mathematical mind.

Note further that the extra dimensions that string theorists are typically cooking up tend to be extra dimensions which are somehow "curled in upon themselves", like a torus is a 2D surface where both dimensions curl in on themselves. So this can be a very mathematically abstract thing, and simple attempts to visualize these dimensions may fail for those reasons.